# Implementing multirecord editing with ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

[image]

How should I design redux architecture for multirecord editing like this?

Currently I store errors in each Tag component. On field blur I do validation and update this.errors. If there are no errors, I make API call and it returns errors I update errors.

I imagine that save({tag}) should handle the validation/save/udate/server errors, however I am mostly confused about how reducer should "find" tags in store. Should it be by index or id? If by id, which I think is better, then how will I know object is persisted or not? (I have in store both saved and not saved objects)

Can share some ideas how to approach it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the mixing of persisted and not persisted objects is overcomplicating the state management and "Add tag" should allow to add only single object at a time with its own state/reducer "newTag". That would be much closer to regular CRUD workflow where we have separate pages for index / new / edit.

The only problem that remains is how to manage errors state. The reason why I would like to store errors in state is usecase when user removes Category on other page and makes some Tags invalid. This however could be addressed in different way: if user removes Category, we remove all Tags related to it. And if that was not desired (lets say you dont want to remove Post because a Category was removed), then I could again build a dedicated state/reducer called "postsWithoutCategory" and based on it notify user that some posts are missing category. Then the whole "tags" state/reducer become regular CRUD state/reducer and errors are managed outside or redux - in form component (either as this.errors or via Angular2 reactive form validations).